# Create DLL to access database c#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, dll

Would it be wise to Use a Dll to access a database When a application starts.

This is the code i have to call in every page in my app

```
  SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
    myConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=CRYSTAL5\\INSTANCE1;Initial Catalog=Pharmacy;Integrated Security=True";
    myConnection.Open();
```

and the dll code i wrote

```
public  class DBConnect
    {
        public DBConnect()
        {
            Initialize();
        }
        private SqlConnection connection;
        //Constructor


    //Initialize values
    private void Initialize()
    {
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "Data Source=CRYSTAL5\\INSTANCE1;Initial Catalog=Pharmacy;Integrated Security=True";

        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }
```

i then added `using DBCon;` in my app and tried to run this code

```
DBConnect myConnection = new DBConnect();
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select doc_fname,doc_lname,gender,department,education ,NMC_no  from ph.doctor_info where unit_id =0", myConnection);
```

it won't work.

sorry for the crappy description

The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.SqlCommand(string, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)' has some invalid arguments
    is the error i get

What would i do without stack overflow.

Comment: If you're asking why that line fails, could you post more code? Is `Initialize()` ever called?

Comment: "it won't work" is not very helpful. What happens and what did you expect to happen? Do you get an error message?

Comment: You try to create a SqlCommand with your own DBConnect object instead of an SqlConnection Instance. That won't work. You could add a CreateSqlCommand-Method to DBConnect, so that DBConnect would create the command object and inject the SqlConnection instance before passing the command back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an object of type "DbConnect" to SqlCommand rather than an SqlConnection object. Your sql connection object is held within this class, in the `connection` variable.

You will either need to make this field public, or alternatively create a function which returns the data connection.

If making connection public, you would then do:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select doc_fname,doc_lname,gender,department,education ,NMC_no  from ph.doctor_info where unit_id =0", myConnection.connection);
```

EDIT: Also in Initialise, you have created the SqlConnection object, but not called `Open()`. You will need to do this before trying to use the connection. Either add `connection.Open()` to initialise(), or call `myConnection.connection.Open()` prior to calling the SqlCommand.

Answer (score 2):

DBConnect doesn't seem to expose the SqlConnection object. Therefore you're passing a DBConnect object into the SqlCommand constructor rather than a SqlConnection object, hence the error.